# Cant Change Friction of Player In Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am extremely new to both Unity and C# and have been working on it for a few days. I'm currently trying to stop my player from sliding and to do this I've set the friction value of the players material high so that it doesn't slide. This however creates an issue where my character travels entirely too fast. To get around this I created a child object with a BoxCollider2D tagged as Friction Controller that I can modify. I get a code that changes the friction value of the physics material to 0 when i start moving and 100 when am supposed to stop. The problem is that while this updates the material itself it does not affect the box colliders settings. Does anybody know a solution for this?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameObject frictionController;
    public BoxCollider2D collider;

    public float speed = 400f;
    public float jumpForce;
    private float friction;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private bool isMoving;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void FixedUpdate()
    {




        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");


        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal,0);


        rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed);


    }
    void Update()
    {
        frictionController = GameObject.FindWithTag("Friction Controller");
        collider = frictionController.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();



        if (Input.GetKey("a") || (Input.GetKey("d")))
        {
            { Debug.Log("Pressed Button"); }
           collider.sharedMaterial.friction = 0;

        }   else { collider.sharedMaterial.friction = 100; }
///This part isn't complete yet

        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector2 jump = new Vector2(0, moveVertical);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            rb2d.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's sliding because of the easing that `Input.GetAxis` does? Try using `Input.GetAxisRaw` instead

Comment: That didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your approach is a particularly good one and is likely to give you problems later on.  Since you're using the physics system, a better approach would be to apply a force to your Rigidbody that is the OPPOSITE of its velocity when want it to come to a stop.

Nevertheless here is a solution that effectively does what you want to do using a similar approach to what you're attempting.  Rather than manipulating the physics material properties, this solution manipulates the drag value of the rigidbody.

```
public class Player_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private float speed = 100f; 

    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal,0);
        rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)))
        {
           rb2d.drag = 5; // Adjust this value to modify speed
        }   
        else 
        { 
            rb2d.drag = 100; // Adjust this value to modify slippery-ness
        }
    }
}
```